# Show sources in footnotes

Tags: bibtex, footnotes

How can I format my LaTeX document so that I see my sources in the footnotes?

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
%linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,% PDF VIEW
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\OnehalfSpacing
%\linespread{1.3}

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{lyhne}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}


\begin{document}

Da aber ein Luftpaket nicht eingeschlossen werden kann, ist eine solche Zustandsänderung in der Atmosphäre unwarscheinlich. \cite[S. 203]{sylvie}


\bibliography{literature}

\end{document}
```

Here a couple of bib entries:

```
@Book{sylvie, 
  title = {Fondamentaux de Météorologie}, 
  publisher = {Cépaduès-Éditions}, 
  year = {2009}, 
  author = {Sylvie Malardel}, 
  editor = {Meteo France}, 
  edition = {2}, 
  month = jan }

@Book{vladimir, 
  title = {Fundamentals of Lightning}, 
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press}, 
  year = {2016}, 
  author = {Vladimir A. Rakov}, 
  month = {April} }
```

Comment: Add those entries to your question post instead of as comments, please.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for example can you use `\footnote{\cite[S. 203]{sylvie}}`.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{sylvie, 
  title = {Fondamentaux de Météorologie}, 
  publisher = {Cépaduès-Éditions}, 
  year = {2009}, 
  author = {Sylvie Malardel}, 
  editor = {Meteo France}, 
  edition = {2}, 
  month = jan,
}
@Book{vladimir, 
  title = {Fundamentals of Lightning}, 
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press}, 
  year = {2016}, 
  author = {Vladimir A. Rakov}, 
  month = {April},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
%linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,% PDF VIEW
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\OnehalfSpacing
%\linespread{1.3}

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{lyhne}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}


\begin{document}

Da aber ein Luftpaket nicht eingeschlossen werden kann, ist eine solche Zustandsänderung in der Atmosphäre unwarscheinlich. \footnote{\cite[S. 203]{sylvie}} %\footcite[S. 203]{sylvie}


\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Or you can use package `biblatex` to get a command `\footcite` ...

With package `natbib` you can add to the given code in the preambel

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

and change `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
```

with the result (only footnote):

[image]

Complete MWE with `natbib`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{sylvie, 
  title = {Fondamentaux de Météorologie}, 
  publisher = {Cépaduès-Éditions}, 
  year = {2009}, 
  author = {Sylvie Malardel}, 
  editor = {Meteo France}, 
  edition = {2}, 
  month = jan,
}
@Book{vladimir, 
  title = {Fundamentals of Lightning}, 
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press}, 
  year = {2016}, 
  author = {Vladimir A. Rakov}, 
  month = {April},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} % <=================================================
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
%linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,% PDF VIEW
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\OnehalfSpacing
%\linespread{1.3}

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{lyhne}
%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % <========================================


\begin{document}

Da aber ein Luftpaket nicht eingeschlossen werden kann, ist eine solche Zustandsänderung in der Atmosphäre unwahrscheinlich. \footnote{\cite[S. 203]{sylvie}} %\footcite[S. 203]{sylvie}


\bibliography{\jobname} % <===== to use the bib file created with filecontents 

\end{document}
```

I used package `filecontents` only to have bib file and TeX code concatenated to one compilable MWE. You can of course your own bib file `literature.bib`! Read the documentation of `filecontents` with `texdoc filecontents` please.

Comment: How would it look like with natbib. Would it show me the name of the autor in the footnote?

Comment: what do you mean by biblatex? Because it still doesn't work ;(